# How to exclude page from sitemap.xml using gatsby

Tags: gatsby, sitemap

I have this page URL: [https://www.example.com/en/ir-news/[...]/](https://www.example.com/en/ir-news/%5B...%5D/)

and I am using plugin: gatsby-sitemap-builder I have already exclude pages like below:

```
  excludes: [
                
                `/en/footer`,
                
              ],
```

like footer page above and now I want to exclude page:  [https://www.example.com/en/ir-news/[...]/](https://www.example.com/en/ir-news/%5B...%5D/)
and I am doing like below:

```
                    excludes: [
                    
                    `/en/ir-news/[...]`, // also tried to remove en from start but did not work
                    
                  ],
```

can anyone recommend where I am doing wrong?

Comment: For dynamic routes like /en/ir-news/[...], the square brackets indicate that it's a dynamic path. However, Gatsby doesn't use square brackets in the URLs directly. Instead, it uses templates in the src/pages directory to generate pages with dynamic content. To exclude dynamic pages from the sitemap, you can use wildcard patterns. 

`excludes: [
          "/en/ir-news/*"
        ]`